# OctoberCMS, comparing a record string to a string

Tags: twig, octobercms

I'm attempting to clean up my Titles in my October CMS Project and I'm running into an issue.

I have a set of pages set to be "Singles" and thus have the title [category]-single which is not great.

So to that end I'm trying to use the [x] in [y] function in twig for an if function as follows;

```
{% else if ('single' in this.page.baseFileName) %}
<title>[formatted title]</title>
{% else %}
```

this doesn't help and throws an "Unexpected token "name" of value "if" ("end of statement block" expected)." exception.

No variation I can think of (bracketing out the record pointer, for example) and I'm reaching an impasse on this.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are adding extraspace to `else if` just remove it and use `elseif`

```
{% elseif ('single' in this.page.baseFileName) %}
{#  ^ use like this #}
<title>[formatted title]</title>
{% else %}
```

docs : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: That got it. Thanks